# How to change the background and color of text in the vega-lite visualization using checkbox?

Tags: kibana, vega-lite, vega

Maybe you can help.
I wanted to create a checkbox that allows you to change the background and color of the text.
I got an example using checkbox and fillOpacity (*the fill opacity (value between [0,1]*), [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQUOQDMaZNKGI04Ady0gImAE5sA1nDQhTSWRBxITcWZhABfd0scmkCCGgA2qCyflboAMowbAZKTDSyACaGCTgMbuiwcFDmTGwAHh7uALpKiUiYKKjaSIIMcAGowSBVAEwAHCVeIExIOWRmDEnWbL6yZFZKyCbmhpgAnjjhNnD5bkrqgoLWzskbcpgRNABe4QCMAAwX3S4qiQma1SCbggDyjlB084YqSXTs8iexFq9TQFyUEDggmymAB1iiMQ8SmBdXO3UwqwyoHUUOS6BQSgWS2sAEcGHZYZVYaQiu4gA). This code does not work in Kibana (*error:cannot find a selection named "Show"*), changed the fields, [source](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4870)

```
"params": [{
   "name": "Show",
   "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}
}]
```

to

```
"selection": {
  "Show": {
    "type": "single",
    "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}
  }
 }
```

[editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQUOQDMaZNKGI04Ady0gImAE5sA1nDQhTSWRBxITcWZhABfd0ohxBcKJjs8qigAMowbAYhNgCeOFboEDSyZH6KIEzJACaGyTgMbuiw-uZMbAAeHp5KWUiYKNHESIIMcBBoANqgDQBMABzuALpeGUhQ5mRmDLI56GwmdmRWSsgm5oaYcQk2cOVuSuqCgtbOOQdymKE0AF4JAIwADA8jLipZyZrRh4IA8o5QdBihhUMzoQUMTRaCQe3l8-kCcms4UiHiUkNaaDuI0wu0KoHUvlmIBQSk28WsAEcGHZAvVAqQqu4gA), [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx64x.png)

Now the code works in Kibana and vega editor and not correct. But this is only a layout, is it technically possible to change the background and color of the entire text in the showcase?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
    "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}},
    
    "selection": {
        "Show": {
        "type": "single",
        "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}
        }
    },
    
    "data": {"values": [{"a": 28}]},
    
    "background": "orange",
    
    "mark": {"type": "text", "fill": "red","fontSize": 100},
    
    "encoding": {
        "fillOpacity": {
        "condition": {"value": 0, "selection": "Show"},
        "value": 1
        },
        "text": {
        "field": "a",
        "type": "quantitative"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to change the background and color of the text by simply using the `expr` config with your param name which is binded with the `checkbox`.
In the mentioned [issue](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4870), the reason is stated why checkbox is not used with the `selection` terms, so params were introduced and an example is given in that url.

But you can refer the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQUOQDMaZNKGI04Ady0gImAE5sA1nDQhTSWRBxITcWZhABfd0scmkCCGgA2qCyflboAMowbAZKTDSyACaGCTgMbuiwcFDmTGwAHh7uALpKiUiYKKjaSIIMcAGowSBVAEwAHCVeIExIOWRmDEmGcPk4JtZRMQAEAPzTAOQAnnCCgjEL06iLbL6yZHALHkrIJuaGmEs44TajbkrqayNjE5HRenOLzomb28ur6z0R26qjkmAiNAAXuEAIwABjh3RcKkSCU01Vu+QyoHUq2S6BQSku12sAEcGHZMHQKjRSEV3EA) and below snippet for background and text color change:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}},
  "params": [{"name": "Show", "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}}],
  "data": {"values": [{"a": 28}]},
  "background": {"expr": "Show ? 'yellow' : 'orange'"},
  "mark": {
    "type": "text",
    "fill": {"expr": "Show ? 'red' : 'yellow'"},
    "fontSize": 100
  },
  "encoding": {"text": {"field": "a", "type": "quantitative"}}
}
```